# How to add apostrophe for email validation in Xml?

Tags: asp.net, xml, validation

Actually, Front end of my registration web page is done in asp.net and the Form validation is done in Xml. In asp.Net given the link for validation from Xml file.

In Xml file, i need to add apostrophe for email validation in that code. Email validator type is predefined. So, i used a generic type to customize the email validation. but its accepting _,-,. except Apostrophe(').
please provide me a generic syntax for email validation...???

please help me as soon as possible guys...!!!

Comment: Email validation in XML? To me that seems non standard (and a bit strange... :). You'll have to provide us with some of your code for us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to do is In validation, I'm using generic customized value to accept apostrophe for emails

Comment: Code for Email validation using generic type: ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-'])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$ I'm using this syntax for validation, but its validating fine except apostrophe. please do me needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the answer for my question email validation using customized generic type.
In that Generic type, I used pattern wise syntax to validate all emails include apostrophe. Now, It will accept the apostrophe who and have with their emails.

Syntax is:

**^([a-z0-9_.\'-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+.[a-z.]+$;**

Now It's working fine.

Thank you for your support Friends....!!!

Comment: This syntax will work for Customized Email validation in xml.